# Kotlin is ignoring expression

Tags: kotlin

I'm wondering why the below code generates the strange results, and compiler doesn't show any error or warning. This looks like an extremely efficient source of bugs.

```
    val a = 10 * 20 +
            10 * 30

    val b = 10 * 20
          + 10 * 30

    val c = (
               (10 * 20)
             + (10 * 30)
            )

    val d = (10 * 20)
          + (10 * 30)

    println(a)
    println(b)
    println(c)
    println(d)
```

And the output is:

```
500
200
500
200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like I was lucky to use an operator which also has unary version `+`.
The problem is that Kotlin allows for a kind of expressions which do nothing in fact like this:

```
12345
```

I can also have:

```
- 12345
```

which is just a negative number. I can also have positive number:

```
+ 12345
```

So in this case:

```
val a = 20 +
        30
```

I have one expression, as the `+` requires another argument, which can be found in the next line.

However here I have two expressions

```
val a = 20
       + 30
```

The variable `a` will have value `20` and the second expression will do nothing.

However there is no unary version of `*`, so this works:

```
val a = 10 * 
        20
```

and `a == 200`, and this makes a compilation error:

```
val a = 10
        * 20 

Error:(397, 17) Kotlin: Expecting an element
```

Adding semicolons doesn't change anything, as the last expression is still not valid, and causes the compilation error.

And you can always use brackets:

```
val x = (10
         + 20)
```

Comment: The problem doesn't exist in Java e.g. since you have a mandatory semicolon, the optionality causes certain problems

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin has optional semicolons, it allows and encourages source code to omit a statement separator (i.e. semicolon `;`). As a result, it can get hard for the compiler to guess what you, as a programmer, actually intend to do:

```
val b = 10 * 20
       + 10 * 30
```

Will be compiled to an assignment of `b = 500` and a second statement that results in `300` but never gets assigned to anything (same with `d`). How would you consider the compiler to know that the second line is actually part of the first expression? It's valid on its own.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39319228/8073652) gives further details.