# Newbe on printing Types

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to follow the "Head First Kotlin" book exercises and I wrote the following code:

```
val numList = arrayOf(1,2,3);
var x = 0;

fun main() {
    while (x < 3) {
        println("Item $x is $numList[x]");
        x += 1;
    }
}
```

Kotlin printed:

```
Item 0 is [Ljava.lang.Integer;@30f39991[x]
Item 1 is [Ljava.lang.Integer;@30f39991[x]
Item 2 is [Ljava.lang.Integer;@30f39991[x]
```

But I expected to be:

```
Item 0 is 1
Item 1 is 2
Item 3 is 3
```

*What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: And just FYI, the [semicolons `;` are not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39319228/1431750) in Kotlin. They are inferred in most cases, with exceptions listed in the linked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing are curly braces, try:

```
println("Item $x is ${numList[x]}");
```

Explanation: `numList[x]` is actually a method call. When using Kotlin's String interpolation you have to use `{}` when accessing the result of a method, function, or accessing a property. Without them, Kotlin inteprets your code as you'd like to print an array (which in Java and Kotlin does not override `toString` method, hence the 'strange output') and a string [x].

Examples:

```
val propertyAccess = "This is a ${user.name}"
val methodCall = "The result is ${anObject.getResult()}"
val functionCall = "5th Fibonacci number is ${fib(5)}"
```