# How kotlin compiler understands the end of statement if semicolon is optional in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, semicolon-inference

In java we use semicolon, on the basis on semicolon compiler understands an end of a statement.

Whereas `Kotlin` also uses JVM How the compiler understands this is the end of statement without semicolon in `Kotlin`?

Comment: Not sure the JVM has anything to do with it - it interprets bytecode and doesn’t care very much about language syntax. How do _you_ think `kotlinc` determines the end of a statement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318457/what-are-the-rules-of-semicolon-inference

Comment: Note that not all statements in Java end with a semicolon. For example, the conditional statement (e.g. `if (someCondition) {}`) doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#string-templates),

> In Kotlin, semicolons are optional, ***and therefore line breaks are
> significant.***

this essentially means `kotlinc` can identify the end of a statment in same manner as `javac` does, only difference is the character that marks the end of statement, where `javac` looks for `;`, `kotlinc` would look for a `\n` (line break).

### Please note that use of semicolon is required when declaring an enum class in kotlin.

for example following code will not compile if you omit the semicolon

```
enum class Fruit(val price: Double) {
    MANGO(100.0);

    fun printPrice(){
        print(price)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Supplementary Answer**

Kotlin lexer parser is smart enough in token-zing the plain text code based on the line breaks through the [`TruncatedSemanticWhitespaceAwarePsiBuilder` interface](https://appdoc.app/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/0.14.449/org/jetbrains/kotlin/parsing/TruncatedSemanticWhitespaceAwarePsiBuilder.html).

This line break recognition is done without having to insert (or replace them with semicolons). Check the [discussion here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-design-principles-contribute-to-the-effectiveness-of-kotlins-asi/15281)

[`SemanticWhitespaceAwarePsiBuilderImpl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/d62254282409bda6fc870bdef35f5df6d9ba7b18/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/parsing/SemanticWhitespaceAwarePsiBuilderImpl.java) is a an implementation to this interface which has [newlineBeforeCurrentToken()](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/d62254282409bda6fc870bdef35f5df6d9ba7b18/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/parsing/SemanticWhitespaceAwarePsiBuilderImpl.java#L70-L102) method that gives some clue on how that works:

```
@Override
public boolean newlineBeforeCurrentToken() {
    if (!newlinesEnabled.peek()) return false;

    if (eof()) return true;

    // TODO: maybe, memoize this somehow?
    for (int i = 1; i <= getCurrentOffset(); i++) {
        IElementType previousToken = rawLookup(-i);

        if (previousToken == KtTokens.BLOCK_COMMENT
                || previousToken == KtTokens.DOC_COMMENT
                || previousToken == KtTokens.EOL_COMMENT
                || previousToken == SHEBANG_COMMENT) {
            continue;
        }

        if (previousToken != TokenType.WHITE_SPACE) {
            break;
        }

        int previousTokenStart = rawTokenTypeStart(-i);
        int previousTokenEnd = rawTokenTypeStart(-i + 1);

        assert previousTokenStart >= 0;
        assert previousTokenEnd < getOriginalText().length();

        for (int j = previousTokenStart; j < previousTokenEnd; j++) {
            if (getOriginalText().charAt(j) == '\n') {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And this is called whenever a token needs to be checked:

```
private boolean tokenMatches(IElementType token, IElementType expectation) {
    if (token == expectation) return true;
    if (expectation == EOL_OR_SEMICOLON) {
        if (eof()) return true;
        if (token == SEMICOLON) return true;
        if (myBuilder.newlineBeforeCurrentToken()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, `newlineBeforeCurrentToken()` parses character by character and compares it to a line break, and eventually returns true to indicate that it's a complete statement.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, Semicolons are optional, but line breaks are significant.

The Kotlin compiler usually recognizes the end of a statement even without an explicit `;` for example by a line break.

**Important:** If you want to put several statements in a single line, they are separated with `;`

For Example :

```
    val a = 42 ; println(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons add no human-valuable meaning to the code. Life’s too short to bother with them. This is only one (admittedly minor) of many examples of non-essential complexity in Java that is removed by more modern JVM languages.